# Sequelize help (throw new Error(`Unrecognized datatype for attribute "${this.name}.${name}"`);)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Here is the GitHub repo for this project: https://github.com/SethZygner/full-stack-testing

I am trying to use Sequelize to use CRUD in MySQL.

```
    return sequelize.define("test", {
        PersonID: {
            type: Sequelize.INT
        },
        Name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    });
};
```

When I run this in the terminal with *node server.js* it gives me this error:
`` throw new Error(`Unrecognized datatype for attribute "${this.name}.${name}"`); ``

As well as the error `Error: Unrecognized datatype for attribute "test.PersonID"`

Again, I'm not sure exactly how this works given my little knowledge on using Sequelize. So the repo will be more help to get a better idea.

For reference, MySQL has a database called *DB* and a table within it called *test*

Answer (score 0):

There is no such data type in Sequelize as `Sequelize.INT`. Replace it with `Sequelize.INTEGER`. See [numeric data types](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#numbers)